# Why forked process started from the beginning?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm trying to understand how fork works. With this code sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char  a = 7;
  char b = 0;
  for (char i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    
    putchar(a+48);
        putchar(b+48);
            putchar(i+48);
    putchar(' ');
    fork();
    b = 3;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've got this result:

```
700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734 700 731 732 733 734
```

It seems that every new forked process created with start from the beginning of the main, but I expected that new process continued from the same place where fork called.

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout)` right before the `fork`.

Comment: Thank you! fflush helped me to understand.